# "You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile." error when running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a basic rails app. I've got a simple controller with route set up, as well as a model. I have the migration file updated, but whenever I run rake db:migrate it gives me a "You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile." error. I tried updating the bundler, which seemed to work fine(outputted "Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1"), but the error persisted.

Comment: What error? Could you be specific?

Comment: That's the error. "You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem seems to be that there is a bundler version mismatch from the repo you've cloned and your local system.

You can update your local bundler version and then do `bundle update` in order for your Gemfile.lock file to have your bundler version (or) you can prepend `bundle exec` before rake task, e.g., `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and you should be fine.

Hope it helps!